# Outputting text from multiple elements on the page - Protractor, Javascript

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm working on Protractor automation framework. I want to output text value from multiple elements on the page.

All elements have a text that I want to output in span tag. So, I have made this helper for me:

```
static getAllSpansContainText (text: string) {
  return this.getAllSpanByText(text, true);
}
```

I use the above method here :

```
static get jobStasuses(){
    return CommonPage.getAllSpansContainText('ACCEPTED');    
}
```

On my test class, I use this:

```
console.log('Job Statuses: '+ffcPage.jobStasuses);
```

I expect this to print out the text 'ACCEPTED' the number of times it is present on the page. But I get :

```
Job Statuses: [object Object]
```

I'm novice, so please bear this question if it seems silly.

Comment: `Object.toString()` is always (unless set otherwise) `[object Object]`

Comment: Please show the function: `getAllSpanByText()`

Comment: @yong The function is mentioned above

Comment: @UzIT, I ask function `getAllSpanByText`, not `getAllSpansContainText`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to resolve the promises. element.all returns a promise thats why you get [object]. So you'll need to use `.then(function(resolved_object));` since you have multiple elements, you need to loop throgh it by holding the element as shown in the code below. You'll again need to resolve currentElement.getText() since it returns a promise as well. code snippet is below. Hope it helps

```
var elementBySpan = element.all(by.xpath('//span')); // returns a promise and not the array objects. you need to resolve it by using .then

  elementBySpan.then(function(varEleBySpan){
     for(i=0; i<varEleBySpan.length; i++){
       (function(currentElement){
          currentElement.getText().then(function(txtValue){
            console.log("Job Statuses: " + txtValue) // this will display the text value of each span in the page
        });   
       })(varEleBySpan[i]);
     }
  });
```